# Difference b/w a normal app & app that was developed by phonegap frame work

Tags: android, cordova

Currently, I'm developing an application for Android OS. I would like to know the difference b/w the applications that were developed using Java framework and the apps developed using PhoneGap framework.

Please help me out this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PhoneGap apps use Html,CSS and javascript.
We can develop apps with the ease of developing a website.

The main advantages that a PhoneGap app are **Multi-platform support** and **easy designing.**

But phonegap apps are **just web apps + features provided by its API's.**
Advanced apps can't be developed with it.
In normal android development,dealing with java and xml is a bit difficult.
Some may feel designing with XML is tedious.

In short,

if you are developing a simple app or a cross-platform app use PhoneGap

If your app needs advanced features better go with normal development.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know,I don't think there is much of a difference really.

Both `Java` and `PhoneGap`have excellent and easy to follow guides for setting up the Android project.I had read somewhere that `PhoneGap` helps wrapping of web apps in a native application wrapper to allow deployment to multiple platforms.

I haven't started off with `PhoneGap` to be honest and I might be wrong.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thnks for the help.and one more thing actually i have developed helloworld app using www.phonegap.com site eclipse IDE with no errors bt am unable to view any thing in android emulator can u plz help me in this thing also??

Comment: see this: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/phonegap/creating-an-android-hello-world-application-with-phonegap/ It works fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Phone gap  app is built in html5 and uses things like jquery to access database

android app uses java and xml to do the app

phonegap can be run on crossplatforms like android and iphone both by just writng few line of code

while otherwise we have to make different codes for both platforms

Answer (score 0):

PhoneGap is essentially a web app that lives in your phone and pretends to be a "real" App, it offers the advantage of being easily portable to multiple platforms, since most platforms can show a WebView inside an App.

They don't have the same responsiveness as native Apps though, and you can tell something is just not right. So definitely don't use them for anything too heavy.
 They also tend to look strange on some platforms because they don't follow the native UI conventions.